# Firefox crashes due to plugin

Tags: firefox, crash

Often, when using FireFox and IE at the same time (IE is open so I can run a Java app to RDP to my work via Cisco), Firefox crashes with the following error message

```
Firefox plugin container has stopped working
```

I looked into EventViewer and it shows some more detail and points to a file. This is what I think is the relevant part of the file

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=130571560112814916
ReportType=2
Consent=1
ReportIdentifier=9fed8388-4e17-11e4-bc1b-c86000deec15
IntegratorReportIdentifier=9fed8387-4e17-11e4-bc1b-c86000deec15
WOW64=1
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=plugin-container.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=32.0.3.5379
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=54224e6b
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name   ******
Sig[3].Value=mozalloc.dll       ******
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=32.0.3.5379
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=54221b67
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=80000003
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=0000141b
```

I have starred 2 lines in the above to show the point of interest. I Google this, and the [suggestion to fix it](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1016465) is to install Shockwave. I have done that, and the fault still occurs.

I have disabled all the Firefox plugins.

I have also just experienced it again, and this time the event log showed me something I didn't notice... Multiple times a second, I'm getting Error events.

Both events appear to be about cscan (a Cisco component) and also hostscan_unknown (which I guess is also due to Cisco)

Any way, the relevant part (I think) is the cscan error which shows

```
The following information was included with the event: 

[cscan][error][restore_directory] no restore folder exists (C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\.backup\Profiles)
```

I'm lost as to what I can do

Comment: Do you use a Cisco VPN client?

Comment: @Jan, not totally sure I understand. The Java app utilizes Cisco but, there is no cisco software under Add Remove programs. However, when I run the Java app, it does say the publisher is Cisco Systems Inc

Comment: cscan.exe is the name of a Cisco VPN client software... perhaps the crashes are due to that?

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, I noticed that in task manager there was something called plug-in container for firefox (under the Description column). So, with FireFox open, I right clicked on the entry in task manager and ended process. Sure enough, Firefox showed an alert to show that a plug in had crashed.

It was Flash.

I've updated to the latest flash and so far, no fails (meaning, Firefox isn't crashing).

Also, for what ever reason, the event logs have stopped showing errors!

I don't know what role flash has in the situation but, so far it seems like it's fixed it.